# como enviar el resultado de un fetch a un estado con React

Tags: reactjs

estoy usando la api de pokemon

en mi componente card hice un fetch dentro de un useEffect 5 veces en este caso
resolví la promesa y traté de enviarle la propiedad name al estado pokemons
cuando le hago console al estado pokemons obtengo una lista

bulbasaur
ivysaur
venusaur
charmander

pero eso no es un array por lo que no puedo recorrerlo para mostrarlo, trate con pokemons.map pero no funciona
Como podria convertr el resultado del fech en un solo array para asignarlo al estado y poder recorrerlo
Gracias por la ayuda.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Card = () => {
    const pokemonNubers = 5;
    const [pokemons, setPokemos] = useState([])

    useEffect(()=>{

        for(let i=0; i<pokemonNubers; i++){
            fetch(`http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`)
            .then((results)=>{
                return results.json();
            }).then((singlePokemon)=>{
                setPokemos(singlePokemon.name);
            })
        }
    },[]);

    console.log(pokemons);

    return (
        <PokemonCard>
            {
                pokemons.map((singlePokemon)=>{
                     return <h1>{singlePokemon.name}</h1>
                })
            }
        </PokemonCard>
    );
}

const PokemonCard = styled.div`
    background: red;
`

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como el valor de *singlePokemon.name* es un string y *pokemons* es un array  se está reemplazando el valor de *pokemons* a string en cada iteracion del loop :

```
setPokemos(singlePokemon.name);
```

lo más sencillo para que *pokemons* sea un array es usar concat

```
setPokemos( (prev) =>
   prev.concat(singlePokemon.name))
```

, *prev* es el valor actual de pokemons.